# R Programming...For Loop to write to a dataframe

Tags: r

I am trying to download some data from the Internet and there is data across a number of tables over a number of years...I can make the connection and download the various tables per year but it is manual in running the script per year.

I have set up a for loop to iterate through the years and write it to a dataframe, however, every time it loops it overwrites the old data.

I tried to set up a variable using paste() but it won't work, I was wondering if there is a solution to what I am asking.

Here is the code I am using...

```
for(year in 2000:2010)
{
    url_team <- "x"
    team <- 'x'
    url <- paste(
        "http://www.ab.com/team/",url_team,"/",year,".htm", sep="")  
    table <- readHTMLTable(url, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}
```

Comment: You have to combine `paste` and `assign`. So, something like `assign(paste0("table_", year), readHTMLTable(url, stringsAsFactors=F))`. But you'd be better off storing the tables in a list and then converting that list to a data frame.

Comment: Great stuff! Thanks a lot, that worked. As for storing as a list I will look into how to do that.

Comment: Great! Like I said, for stuff like that, it's better to create a list and fill in the list. That way you only have one variable in your workspace instead of 10. I'll post an answer below that shows both ways so you can accept and close out the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to use the `assign` function with the `paste` function. That would look like this:

```
for (year in 2000:2010) {
  url_team <- "x"
  team <- 'x'
  # paste0 automatically sets the sep argument to ""
  url <- paste0("http://www.ab.com/team/", url_team, "/", year, ".htm")  
  assign(paste0("table_", year), readHTMLTable(url, stringsAsFactors=F))
}
```

`assign` will create new variables based on the name you pass it. The downside is that you now have 11 variables in your workspace, which just clutters everything. Instead, you should just use a list object to keep it all in one place. That would look like this:

```
tables = vector(mode="list", length=11)
for (i in 1:11) {
  year <- 1999 + i
  url_team <- "x"
  team <- 'x'
  url <- paste0("http://www.ab.com/team/", url_team, "/", year, ".htm")  
  tables[[i]] <- readHTMLTable(url, stringsAsFactors=F)
}
names(tables) <- as.character(2000:2010)
```

Now you can call each table by using `tables$2000` or `tables$2003` or the like. In the end you have all 11 tables, but only one variable.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work up to a point, it creates the tables as tables$2000, tables$2001, etc., but all the tables contain the data of the last value of year so seems to be doing same thing as my original problem. I tried merging your original solution but it still overwrites the data.

Comment: @antimuon I'm not sure why it would. Unless there's something up with the url and `readHTMLTable` is grabbing the same data over and over. I can't replicate the error because I don't know the real URL you're trying to use.

Comment: @brittenb...my bad, I spotted a typo in what I did, I found out the variable year was not being set so I took a closer look, I had year < 1999+i, not year <- 1999+i...works great! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using `lapply()` for a list of data frames from the html tables. And then run a `do.call(rbind, ...)` to bind all data frames into one master data frame:

```
dflist <- lapply(2000:2010, function(year){
                url_team <- "x"
                team <- 'x'
                url <- paste0("http://www.ab.com/team/",url_team,"/",year,".htm")  
                readHTMLTable(url, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
          })

finaldf <- do.call(rbind, dflist)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)

data_frame(url_team = "x",
           team = "x",
           year = 2000:2010) %>%
  mutate(url = paste0("http://www.ab.com/team/",
                     url_team,"/",year,".htm") ) %>%
  group_by(year, team) %>%
  do(readHTMLTable(.$url, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) )
```

Also, if you have multiple teams:

```
team = data_frame(team = c("x", "y"),
                  url_team =  c("x", "y") )
year = data_frame(year = 2000:2010)

merge(year, team) %>%
  mutate(url = paste("http://www.ab.com/team/",
                     url_team,"/",year,".htm", sep="") ) %>%
  group_by(year, team) %>%
  do(readHTMLTable(.$url, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) )
```

Comment: @bramtayl, thanks. I tried that out and it creates a matrix output of year, team and table but I can't seem to access the table...I will try again later when I get a chance.